# How to properly set the min-height and the max-height to the panel and hide anything that is overflow?

Tags: html, css, panel

I have panel

[image]

I want to set a `min-height`, and `max-height` to 850px; to my right panel right. ]

---

## GOAL

If I don't have anything on the list yet, I still want the panel height to be 850px.

If I have so many added on the list, I do **not** want the panel height to increase beyond 850px.

---

## I've tried

```
.nfTable   {
    min-height: 850px;
    max-height: 850px;
}
```

---

Should I use `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: why not simply `height:850px` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want the panel to be 850px high you do not need to set min or max height.  Min and max height are useful when a block can expand or shrink based on the content and you don't want it to expand or shrink beyond a specific size.  So you should just use `height: 850px;`

If the content in your panel might be longer than 850px you have a couple of options.  You can hide it using `overflow: hidden;` if you don't want to see it at all, or you could use `overflow: auto;` to allow the content to scroll if it exceeds the height of your panel.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more info about the CSS overflow property.